# PyQtGraph doesn't resize

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to make simplest Qt app to visualize some data using pyqtgraph lib. I've created one-window app using Qt Designer, placed there Graphics View widget, promoted it to pygtgraph. In my app (written in python) I create test data set and plot it. This works (graph is displayed correctly) but the graph doesn't re-size with the window. So then, in Qt Designer I set layout of main form to "Lay Out in a grid" and in preview it works fine ("Graphics View" widget resizing with main window). But when I run my app then the plot appears very small, like 5x20 pixels and is not re-sizable.

My app:

```
class AppWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, StartForm.Ui_StartForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        line1 = ([1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3])
        pl = self.graphicsView.plot(line1)  # graphicsView is Graphics View widget from Qt Designer

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = AppWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

generated code by Qt Designer:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_StartForm(object):
    def setupUi(self, StartForm):
        StartForm.setObjectName("StartForm")
        StartForm.resize(1609, 1062)
        self.graphicsView = PlotWidget(StartForm)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(11, 11, 1261, 931))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")

        self.retranslateUi(StartForm)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StartForm)

    def retranslateUi(self, StartForm):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        StartForm.setWindowTitle(_translate("StartForm", "Form"))


from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
```

I've also tried to create pyqtgraph plot from my python app and then embed it into empty layout generated by Qt Designer but the result is the same - plot is not resizable. Seems like it doesn't inherit some properties from main form.

So the question is - why my graph appears very small (doesn't expand to full window as it does in Qt Designer pre-view) and is not re-sizable? How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

- Depending on the code you provide you are not using a layout.
- If you have used the "Widget" template then you must use QWidget as a base class, instead you try to use QMainWindow.

Considering the above I created a .ui

***.ui**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>StartForm</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="StartForm">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="PlotWidget" name="graphicsView"/>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PlotWidget</class>
   <extends>QGraphicsView</extends>
   <header>pyqtgraph</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Then you convert it to .py:

```
pyuic5 your_form.ui -o StartForm.py -x
```

obtaining the following:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_StartForm(object):
    def setupUi(self, StartForm):
        StartForm.setObjectName("StartForm")
        StartForm.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(StartForm)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.graphicsView = PlotWidget(StartForm)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)

        self.retranslateUi(StartForm)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StartForm)

    def retranslateUi(self, StartForm):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        StartForm.setWindowTitle(_translate("StartForm", "Form"))

from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
```

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import StartForm

class AppWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, StartForm.Ui_StartForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        line1 = ([1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3])
        pl = self.graphicsView.plot(line1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AppWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, eyllanesc! It works now. Actually, I've corrected second error (base class) and it worked right away. I had a suspicion that there is something wrong with inheritance but didn't see what. Regarding first error (layout) - I've already tried various combinations earlier today, also with layout but it didn't work because of base class. Anyway, you're right, thanks for your fast help!